# How To make background blur when html popup modal opens?

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I click on a button a popup opens so I want when the popup modal opens, background page gets blurred.

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body" style="max-height:500px;">
            <div class="panel-title text-center" style="width: 99%; padding: 1%;">
                <h1 class="title">Titels</h1>
                <hr style="border: 2px solid;"/>
            </div>

            <div class="table100 ver1 m-b-110">
                <div class="table100-body js-pscroll">
                    <table id="Table" class="display" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                        <tr class="row100 head">
                            <th style="text-align: center" class="cell100 column1">id</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center" class="cell100 column1">name</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center" class="cell100 column1">sname</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center" class="cell100 column1">dname</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is my popup modal code but I don't know how to to make the background blur when this opens.

Comment: Its simple, You can use css blur property , I can design the code for you if you can post the whole thing.

Comment: <body><div>some code</div>  <div class="modal" id="myModal"> modal code</div></body>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can also set property for body using before and after pseudo elements.

```
body:before{
    position:absolute;
    top : 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    content:"";
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index:100;
    opacity: .5

}
```

Comment: It makes the page blur from starting

Comment: you can create on div inside body and give same css to that div, show the div when modal opens and hide when modal close.

Answer (score 2):

Set blur style for the container which behind the modal.

```
body.modal-open .container{
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    -moz-filter: blur(4px);
    -o-filter: blur(4px);
    -ms-filter: blur(4px);
    filter: blur(4px);
    filter: url("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/amitabhaghosh197/b7865b409e835b5a43b5/raw/1a255b551091924971e7dee8935fd38a7fdf7311/blur".svg#blur);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='4');
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/balajidesigner/pen/KbxXYM)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Boostrap then your content is already in some kind of `container`. So you can use CSS `filter` like this:

```
.modal-open .container {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px) grayscale(90%);
    filter: blur(5px) grayscale(90%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Novice programmer here. I'm sure there is unnecessary code here and some bad practices, but this is how I got the background page with all elements to deactivate and blur when opening an unblurred popup. Basically, all elements in the original page are in one div (mainpage) and the popup modal is in its own div (popup). I hope this helps someone else who needs to be walked thru the basics.

CSS:

```
.mainpage {
}
.popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 40%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(181, 43, 43);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  filter: blur(0px);
}
.blur {
  filter: blur(2px);
}
.unblur {
  filter: none;
```

HTML:

```
<body style='background-color: #9999cf'>
<div id='mainpage'>
  <h1><br>Operation Screen</h1>
  <button id='openPopup'>Open Popup</button>
</div>
<div id='popup' class='popup'>
  <h2>Popup</h2>
  <button id='closePopup' onclick='closePopup()'>Close Popup</button>
  <button onclick='applyBlur()'>Apply Blur to Original Page</button>
  <button onclick='removeBlur()'>Remove Blur</button>
</div>
```

Script:

```
function closePopup() 
{
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#mainpage *'); 
  elements.forEach(function(element) {element.disabled = false;});
  document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
  removeBlur();
}
function applyBlur() 
{
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#mainpage *');
  elements.forEach(function(element) {element.classList.add('blur');});
}
function removeBlur() 
{
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#mainpage *');
  elements.forEach(function(element) {element.classList.remove('blur');});
}
document.getElementById('openPopup').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#mainpage *');
  elements.forEach(function(element) {element.disabled = true;});
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  applyBlur();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the opacity via CSS if you are using **Bootstrap** modal.

```
.modal-backdrop
{
    opacity:0.5 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, it should work

```css
.blur-filter {
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
    -moz-filter: blur(2px);
    -o-filter: blur(2px);
    -ms-filter: blur(2px);
    filter: blur(2px);
}
```

check out this CodePen for more details
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/Palestinian/pen/mDKkG)

Comment: There's no element in the HTML which that selector will match.

Comment: Experimental vendor prefixed properties aren't recommended… because they are experimental. All major browsers support `filter` now anyway.